Indirect modification of overloaded property laravel

Indirect modification of overloaded property Modules\Product\Http\Requests\CreateProductRequest::$specification has no effect

    foreach($request->specification as $key => $specification){
        $image = null;
        
        if ($specification['icon']) {
            $path_info = pathinfo($_FILES['specification']['name'][$key]['icon']);
            $randomize = rand(111111, 999999);
            $tmpFile = $_FILES['specification']['tmp_name'][$key]['icon'];
            $image = date('mdYHis') . $randomize . '.' . $path_info['extension'];
            $newFile = 'public/fileimage/'.$image;
            $result = move_uploaded_file($tmpFile, $newFile);
            $specification['icon'] = '';
            // dd($specification['icon'] );
            // $request->specification = $specification; 

        }
        // dd($specification);
        $request->specification[$key] = null;
        dd($request->specification[$key]);
        $request->specification[$key] = $specification;
        dd($request->specification[$key]);
    }

its giving me error Indirect modification of overloaded property. I can't able to update update array value. and not understating the issue.

You cannot modify $request directly. To archive this you have to assign the $request to  variable and work on with it
$specifications = $request->input('specification');


$specifications = $request->input('specification');

foreach($specifications as $key => &$specification){
    if (!empty($specification['icon'])) {
        // your code
    }

    $specifications[$key] = $specification;
}

dd($specifications);


hi. it's only getting input data not file. if i use  $specifications = $request->file('specification'); its remove data from array. so i am not getting both. if i try both facing same error.

@JawwadArif, I couldn't understand what you're trying to say. Can you please elaborate more?
